# Unix systems programming

Tags: unix, system

Where is a good place to start if one is interested in Unix systems programming?

Any recommended reading, tutorials etc that are aimed at the beginner?

What knowledge is needed to start with systems programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with Mark Rochkind's "[Advanced Unix Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543)" if you can find it.  Then graduate to Stevens "[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079)".

Comment: The word "Advanced", is the book still for beginners in systems programming? Do I need to know assembly language?

Comment: No, both books are in C, and Rochkind's is very clear for a moderately skilled programmer.  I first read it in the late 1980s (it's been updated since then).

Comment: Steven's book is very deep and I found it helpful to have read Rochkind's before I delved into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. will take the same route then ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Stevens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949) is the bible. Read and understand this and his other books and you have most of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Systems-Programming-Communication-Concurrency/dp/0130424110](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130424110)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried myself many books for learning the system programming.The best which I found is:
System Programming with C and Unix by Adam Hoover
You can directly start with this book.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this too for anyone interested. Apparently it is the "New standard" for linux programming.
[image]

[The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/LCSR-Computing/programming.html
to program under unix in c and pascal

C and Unix Programming: A Comprehensive Guide
this worked wonders for me

cprogramming.com
I think the best place to learn c and c++ and some other stuff. They also have great suggestions for books (and ebooks).